# Determine if T-SQL select statement returns any rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I want to set a boolean value in a stored procedure. I want to set the value to true if a certain select query returns more than zero rows.

```
Declare @ShowQuotingTool as bit 


(select count(*) from tblAgentsLicensedState where AgentCode = '016893' and StateCode in ('AZ','GA','IA', 'TN', 'SC', 'KS', 'MI' ,'NC', 'UT')) > 0;
```

How do I set `@ShowQuotingTool` to true or false based on the `select` query? I get the error `Incorrect syntax near ">"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just assign `@ShowQuotingTool` to the count query. This is based on the fact that any `count > 0` will set the `bit` variable `@ShowQuotingTool` to true and `count = 0` will set it to false

```
Declare @ShowQuotingTool as bit 

SELECT @ShowQuotingTool = (select count(*) from tblAgentsLicensedState where AgentCode = '016893' and StateCode in ('AZ','GA','IA', 'TN', 'SC', 'KS', 'MI' ,'NC', 'UT'))
```

You should preferably use `EXISTS` which would have better performance than `COUNT` query above.

```
IF EXISTS(select * from tblAgentsLicensedState where AgentCode = '016893' and StateCode in ('AZ','GA','IA', 'TN', 'SC', 'KS', 'MI' ,'NC', 'UT'))
    SET @ShowQuotingTool = 1
ELSE 
    SET @ShowQuotingTool = 0
```

Comment: ughai, This is a very bad solution in my opinion! There is no need to execute the query again in order to get what you already have from the start, or you can get in the first query :-)

Comment: @RonenAriely - We don't know that the procedure does and since OP has not specified it. There might be different flows for `@ShowQuotingTool = 1 ` and `@ShowQuotingTool = 0`. OP could have even used `@@ROWCOUNT` however with given information it's hard to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Good Day,

1. Please post DDL+DML if this is not what you are looking for. In any case please remember next time to post DDL+DML (queries to create the relevant tables and to insert some sample data, in order to give us the tools to reproduce the issue).
2. **Back to your question**:

If you have an SP that return the result of select query (or any DML query), that mean that you need this query to execute as it is. **The idea of using COUNT function on the results mean that you execute another query, which is not logic action to do, since we already have the information in the headers of the result.**

If you notice, by default, every time that you execute a query in the SSMS for example you get the information regarding number of rows: "(x row(s) affected)". There is no need to use another query.

If you are using external application that you develop, and your SP do not use "SET NOCOUNT ON", then this information coming back from the server :-)

You can see examples here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171921.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396